# In a multivariate normal model, what are the consequences of having a large marginal variance (diagonal element) for each random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that we have that $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim N(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ where $\mathbf{0}$ is an $n \times 1$ vector and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a covariance matrix. Suppose that we let the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ be large, like $25$, while keeping the rest of the off-diagonals some correlation parameter $\rho$. I am wondering what the difference is between having a large diagonal element in $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ vs having a smaller diagonal element, like $1$ in the diagonals instead.

It seems asymptotically it might lead to slower convergence when calculating the MLE and associated estimators. However, are there any other reasons why usually people don't have a large variance element and like to keep it at $1$?

Comment: If the elements on the diagonal "grow" then also the elements on other entries. In a covariance matrix we are not dealing with correlation (kept in borders $[-1,1]$) but with covariance.

Comment: What are you estimating with your MLE?

Comment: Your second paragraph is quite unclear to me. I think you'd have to explain what you're doing with far greater specificity before I could address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the off-diagonal correlations $\rho$ are all the same number, then you have
$$
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_3 & \cdots \\ \rho\sigma_2\sigma_1 & \sigma_2^2 & \rho\sigma_2\sigma_3 & \cdots \\
\rho\sigma_3\sigma_1 & \rho\sigma_3\sigma_2 & \sigma_3^2 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Not suppose you just mutltiply all of the diagonal elements, which are the marginal variances, by $25.$ Then all of the off-diagonal entries also get multiplied by $25,$ and the whole matrix becomes $25\Sigma.$ In effect, if the matrix above is $\operatorname{var} X,$ where $X$ is an $n\times1$ random vector, then $25\Sigma = \operatorname{var} (5X).$ So the whole thing just gets re-scaled.

However, since you say the **marginal** variances are what you're concerned with, perhaps you wanted to know what happens if you multiply all of those by some large number while leaving the off-diagonal entries as they are. But in that case, the correlation does not remain the same: If one changes $\sigma_i^2$ to $25\sigma_i^2$ for $i=1,\ldots,n,$ while leaving the $(i,j)$ entry as $\rho\sigma_i\sigma_j$ for $i\ne j,$ then the correlation is no longer $\rho,$ but $\rho/25.$ In effect, you're making the correlations approach $0$ as you increase the factor by which you multiply the diagonal elements. The dependence among the components of $X$ gets weaker.